# WHY my domain points back to previous IP after 1 day

Tags: dns

2 days ago, I applied a domain gtscomputers.com.au, and then changed the nameserver to the one from my hosting, and change all "A Record" to the IP 27.131.74.13.

Yesterday, I applied another IP address 27.131.74.36 and changed all "A Records" to the new IP, this morning the domain has been pointed to the new IP.

However, when I tried to access the website tonight, it has been point back to the previous IP address 27.131.74.13.

I'm using 8.8.8.8 (Google DNS) on my PC, and after I change to ISP's DNS, the website is pointed to the new IP which is correct, because this DNS has not been updated yet.

Can anyone tell me what's going on? I have checked all DSN settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [time to live (TTL)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_to_live) value for your domain name system record tells nameservers how long to cache the old data - unless you explicitly set a low TTL, nameservers will likely respond to DNS lookups with the last cached data until the TTL expires.

Comment: The strange thing is that this morning, the 8.8.8.8 has pointed  the domain name to the new IP address.

Comment: Use `dig` and `dig @server` for troubleshooting if you see the problem recur - hard to isolate the source of the problem otherwise. http://linux.die.net/man/1/dig

Comment: 8.8.8.8 is an anycast address: it is actually a service comprised of a whole bunch of servers sprinkled throughout the world. You can and will get different results from subsequent queries to Google DNS, depending on the cache status of the particular server you hit. It is not surprising that you would see differing resposnses during a DNS change.